# Array as JQuery Widget instance variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, widget

To start - i don't have a full understanding of JQuery widgets. The way i see them are as objects that can hold a state and representation on their own. The examples i used for my design come from the microsoft 'SILK' project.

The problem - As i was busy creating visual elements as JQuery widgets for a new site everything went fine, untill i initialized more then 1 element with the widget. Instance variables (arrays) seemed global as opposed to everything else. So i created a simple test project to demonstrate the behaviour:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($, undefined) {
            $.widget('AR.MultiQueue', {
                options: {
                    queueName: "",
                    Names: [],
                    Wrong: [],
                    Right: []
                },

                _create: function () {
                    var temp = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.Names.length; i++) {
                        console.log('pushing ' + this.options.Names[i] + ' for ' + this.options.queueName);
                        this.options.Wrong.push(this.options.Names[i]);
                        temp.push(this.options.Names[i]);
                    }

                    this.options.Right = temp;
                },

                Test: function () {
                    console.log(this.options.queueName);
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.Names.length; i++)
                        console.log('Name->' + this.options.Names[i]);
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.Wrong.length; i++)
                        console.log('Wrong->' + this.options.Wrong[i]);
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.Right.length; i++)
                        console.log('Right->' + this.options.Right[i]);
                },

                destroy: function () {
                    $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            });
        }(jQuery));

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            $('#a').MultiQueue({ queueName: 'a', Names: ["a"] });
            $('#b').MultiQueue({ queueName: 'b', Names: ["b"] });
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#a').MultiQueue('Test');
                console.log('Next widget');
                $('#b').MultiQueue('Test');
            }, 1000);
        })();


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the output I expected is for each widget to only print out the respective ("a" or "b") array string 3 times. Instead the output is:

```
pushing a for a
pushing b for b
a
Name->a
Wrong->a
Wrong->b
Right->a
Next widget
b
Name->b
Wrong->a
Wrong->b
Right->b
```

As you can see, both the widgets print out "a" AND "b" for the array that uses a direct instance variable 'push'. For now im just rewriting my widgets to use a temporary array object like the 'Right' options var in the example, but i get the feeling there is more to jQuery widgets then i can understand (as in, do i write code the way i should???)

I searched the web for this, but the only thing i can come up with is

- dont use jQuery PLUGINS as instances
- something with jQuery widgets being stored in arrays
- the fact i never really understood arrays in javascript (as the fact arrays have fixed sizes and the closest is a List<> in C#).

Anyway, i really want to know why this is happening (and if i could expect more of these suprises, this took a bit of time to find out)

Thanks

Comment: It just hit me: putting this.options.Wrong = []; at the start of _create also works correct. So it seems there is an old reference to the array when creating the new instance... Don't know why, so the question still stands, but still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `null` instead of `[]` inside the options and only start them on `_create` or `_init`. This happens because the array is instantiated once for that widget type (basically speaking) and kept as a reference for every new widget created. Primitive types are copied (recursively) but arrays are referenced so when jQuery copy the options the array stays the same.

Comment: I accepted your answer as the answer, but i would still like to know WHY this happens and when i can expect this again.. You say '..copy the options the array stays the same' Is that ment as 'why' it happens (so the options can stay the same), or 'what' happens (resulting in the same options)? Because if its ment as 'why', then i don't understand, if its ment as 'what', then in my comment on the original question,i already figured out the reference for the array stayed the same while instantiating a new instance of the widget. Does this only applies to arrays, or also custom objects?